# How to display the first bar in the bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

- As can be seen in the following plot, the first bar is not displayed.
- Why isn't it displayed and how the code be fixed so the bar does display?

```py
import json 
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

i = 0
while i<=2:
    
    key = '4ee91801f78b4271a5d90623210211'
    main_url = 'http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json'
    city = input('Hangi Şehri Almak istiyorsunuz : ')
    
    response = requests.get(main_url, params = {
        'key': key,
        'q': city,
        'lang' : 'tr'
     })
    
    data = response.json()

    c_values = data['current']['temp_c']
        

    if i == 0:
        city1 = city
        c_values1 = c_values
    elif i == 1:
        city2 = city
        c_values2 = c_values 
    else: 
        city3 = city 
        c_values3 = c_values
    
    i = i + 1 

names = [f'{city1}',f'{city2}',f'{city3}']
values = [f'{c_values1}', f'{c_values2}', f'{c_values3}'] 

plt.bar(names,values)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- The issue is `[f'{c_values1}', f'{c_values2}', f'{c_values3}']` is a `list` of `str` types, not numbers.

  - It should be `[c_values1, c_values2, c_values3]` so the y-axis can be plotted correctly with numbers, not text.
  - Notice the bottom value of the bar plot is `'12'`, which is the top of `'Paris'`
  - `['12.0', '11.0', '17.0']` note the values are strings.
- I recommend using `while i<3:` instead of `while i<=2`
- Alternatively, simplify the code

```py
i = 0
cd = dict()  # create an empty dict
while i<3:
    
    key = '4ee91801f78b4271a5d90623210211'
    main_url = 'http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json'
    city = input('Hangi Şehri Almak istiyorsunuz : ')
    
    response = requests.get(main_url, params = {
        'key': key,
        'q': city,
        'lang' : 'tr'
     })
    
    data = response.json()

    cd[city] = data['current']['temp_c']  # add the city and temp to the dict
    i+=1

plt.bar(cd.keys(), cd.values())
plt.show()
```

[image]